# Use of parentheses in PowerShell scripting?

Tags: powershell, grouping, parentheses

Can anyone explain me the difference between following two statements?

1. `gc -ReadCount 2 .\input.txt| % {"@@" + $_}`
2. `(gc -ReadCount 2 .\input.txt)| % {"@@" + $_}`

I am using below file as input for above commands.

**input.txt**

```
1
2
```

**Output**

`gc -ReadCount 2 .\input.txt| % {"@@" + $_}`

@@1  2

`(gc -ReadCount 2 .\input.txt)| % {"@@" + $_}`

@@1
@@2

**If the input file contains more than 2 records both are giving same output.**
I can modify my code to achieve what i want but i am just wondering why these 2 are giving different outputs.

I googled for the information but didn't find any answer.

**Edit 1**

Isn't the output of command 2 wrong, when i specify "-ReadCount 2" it should pipe two lines at a time, that means foreach loop should iterate only once(as input contains only 2 lines) with $*[0]=1 , $*[1]=2 so that when i print "@@"+$_ it should print "@@1 2" as command1 did.

Comment: Unless you use `@()` single object from pipeline does not wrapped into array. As result, when `input.txt` have only two lines, you will get array of strings, but not array of arrays of strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
gc -ReadCount 2 .\input.txt| % {"@@" + $_}
```

Read the content as [String] - Which means it adds "@@" then the whole text file after it (the foreach loop running once)

```
(gc -ReadCount 2 .\input.txt)| % {"@@" + $_}
```

Read the content as [Array] and evaluate each line of it, which adds "@@" and the content of each line after it (the foreach loop running twice)

The `-ReadCount` Parameter are used to split the data to an array of lines as one chunk, mostly used for performance, so `-ReadCount 3` will show

```
@@1 2 3
@@4 5 6
@@7
```

and `-ReadCount 4` will show:

```
@@1 2 3 4
@@5 6 7
```

Comment: There is something I still don't understand about `-ReadCount` because when you remove it, both examples behave the same.

Comment: @Avshalom, when the input file contains more than 2 lines both are giving same output, how is that possible? Say if the file contains 4 lines, then both commands splitting them into 2 groups and giving @@1 2 
                                                                                                @@3 4 
as output

Comment: @Avshalom, you are saying the first command will always pipe entire file to the loop as single string but when there are 4 lines in input, it is spiting them into 2 groups and giving output as @@1 2,@@3 4(in next line). The only problem is with the command2 with 2 lines of input.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone to see, here is the output of `Get-Help Get-Content -Parameter ReadCount`:

```
-ReadCount <Int64>
    Specifies how many lines of content are sent through the pipeline at a time.
    The default value is 1. A value of 0 (zero) sends all of the content at one time.
```

This is what breaks the lines into groups (I assumed it would instead limit the number of lines read in the file).

Still no clue about the *less-than-three-lines* behavior, though.

Comment: 2 is the minimum integer value for the `-ReadCount` that has effect

Comment: yes but why does it behave differently depending on the number of lines in the input file ?

Comment: each chunk must has minimum of two lines so if you have only two lines of text it will has only one chunk